# Conformal map from intersection of circles to the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

I was trying to solve this problem but had problems:

Find a conformal map from $D:=\{z∈C:|z|<1 \quad  \text{and}\quad |z-(1+i)|<1\}$ the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$.

I want to map $D$ to the upper half plane, so I can compose it with the Cayley transformation so I considered $$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z-1}$$ which has $f(i)=0$ and $f(1)=\infty$. This Moebius transformation should supposedly map to a quadrant(though im not sure how to conclude which). After determining the quadrant, I need to find a value $\beta$ such that $f(z)^{\beta}$ maps to the upper half plane. How do I determine these things?

Answer (score 1):

Your f(z) being a mobius transfromation maps cicrlines to circlines. So, it maps the circles |z|=1 and |z-(1+i)|=1 to lines through the origin as their images contain o and infinity. The question remains, which lines? Evaluate any other point on each of the circles. An easy candidate will be the appropriate scalar multiples of 1+i. By appropriate I mean |c(1+i)|=1 and |d(1+i)-(1+i)|=1. Once you know, evaluate these in f to figure out which pair of lines you have. Now, just pick a point in D and evaluate it in f to find which of the four sectors cut out D will map too.

Then, if necessary, apply a rotation so one line lies on the positive reals. Then, raise to the appropriate exponent so that the other line ends up on the negative reals, giving you D mapping to the upper half plane. The exponent is found by finding the angle between the lines. The exponent times this angle (in radians) should equal pi.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand this correctly. Firstly, how can determine the lines by evaluating these scalar multiplies? And if I know the lines, don't I know the sector which D maps to?

Comment: D is bounded by two arcs which start and end at 1 and i. One arc belongs to |z|=1 and the other arc the other circle. We know that this arc maps to some line through the origin after applying f. The question remains, which one! So to determine this, we need only pick any other point on the arc and see where it maps. Out of convenience, I suggested the point on the arc which will be the mid point. c above equals1/ (root 2) for clarity.

No, you know D maps to a region bounded by these lines but apriori you don't know which. You must in some way use that D is inside BOTH |z|=1 and the other.

Comment: Ciarán Ó Raghaillaigh But dont I know that the angle between the lines must be $\pi/2$ since $f$ is conformal(and the circles intersect orthogonally)? Thus, $f$ maps D to a quadrant which I can determine if I know which lines I am dealing with.

Comment: You can definitely use the fact about angles. But that won't tell you which quadrant. And yes, if you know where the arcs map to then you are good. But you must figure this out somehow. Picking points is but one way. There are also orientation considerations that can help.

Comment: I have tried evaluating $f(c(1+i))$ but I dont see how I can determine the line from this given that i know that $|c|=1/\sqrt{2}$